# Find users according to occurences of notifications_sent mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get users with their count on notification_template_id.
Means if a user is targeted more than once with the notification_template_id 56.

E.G

```
user_id   notification_template_id    count
229          56                         3
117          13                         2
```

[image]

the query i am trying is:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    notification_template_id,
    count(notification_template_id) AS cnt
FROM
    user_notifications
GROUP BY
    user_id;
```

but it shows only total count of notifications per user.

Comment: Just `group by notification_template_id` as well, not only by `user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sql is:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    notification_template_id,
    count(notification_template_id) AS count
FROM
    user_notifications
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    notification_template_id;
```